# Unable to play live video using HTML video tag

Tags: android, html, cordova

Wowza Media Server running Live Video Streaming.

When I view the live video using RTMP and HTTP streaming using wowza examples which has live video players I am able to view video for all.

I am also able to run mobile application using cordova(phonegap) for ios devices. I am using HTML video tag in cordova application and I am able to view live video on IPad simulator using HLS streaming but whenever I try to run the same application using android simulator I am not able to view video.

Can someone please let me know what player should be used to run the application in android devices so that I can be able to view the video for Android devices?

Online search has proved that android supports HTML video tag and it should be able to play the HLS stream but when I tried it does not support. 
What video player to use for Android? 
And which stream type to use for Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best Compatibility chart: http://www.projekktor.com/compatibility/