# Steam a live Video using HTML

Tags: html, youtube

How would you display a live video, per say this link as an example? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cXkDHQ3q4o

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/JqdmeK

Working (regular video):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Not-working (live video):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=1cXkDHQ3q4o">
</iframe>
```

This article has an "answer" with a broken link. [Unable to play live video using HTML video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607795/unable-to-play-live-video-using-html-video-tag)

There are not many articles and streaming is becoming a huge deal, so hope this question is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the YouTube video then click:

```
Share -> Embed (<>)
```

You will be given the source code for embedding the iframe for your video on the right:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1cXkDHQ3q4o" 
  frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
  picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Which will then provide the live video for you, see example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgeXVO)

If you want the video to autoplay you need to add the query string `?autoplay=1&mute=1` to [your video URL](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgeXVO):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1cXkDHQ3q4o?autoplay=1&mute=1" 
  frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
  picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```